# changing object values to matching mapped values

Tags: javascript, oop, object, ecmascript-6

I have an Object that looks like this

```
const companyObj = 
    { 
      Advice_Charge: "B. In service / product cost"
      Org_Advisory: "B. 1-3"
      Org_Developers: "A. None"
      Org_MainCategory: "Business services and sales"
      Org_Name: "A1 Orchard Spreading"
      Org_Size_Facing: "B. 1-3"
      Org_SubCategory: "Contractor - Harvesting and cultivation"
    }
```

I have another object that looks like this

```
const sizeMap = {
          'A. None': '11-30',
          'B. 1-3': '1-3',
          'C. 4-10': '4-10',
          'D. 11 - 30': '11-30',
          'E. 31 - 100': '31-100',
          'F. 100 - 300': '100-300',
          'G. 301 - 1000': '301-1000',
          'H. 1,000+': '1000 +',
          'J. ???': '1-3',
        }
```

I am trying to change one of the properties inside the object using the sizeMap

I want `companyObj` to look like this

```
{Org_Size_Facing: '1-3'} // I don't really care about the other properties at this point..
```

Basically if `companyObj.Org_Size_Facing` returns any of the fields from `sizeMap` `sizeMap` should then return the appropriate value

I have tried

```
console.log(
          'objAsign',
          Object.assign(companyObj.Org_Size_Facing, sizeMap['Org_Size_Facing']),
        )
```

This is way off, but I'm sure you guys get the idea of it

Would appreciate any help you guys can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the entries (pairs of key, value) of `companyObj` and use the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check if the property is in the `sizeMap` object (note that it looks also in the prototype chain).

If you only need at least one property, then you can break early.

Running example

```js
const companyObj = {
  Advice_Charge: "B. In service / product cost",
  Org_Advisory: "B. 1-3",
  Org_Developers: "A. None",
  Org_MainCategory: "Business services and sales",
  Org_Name: "A1 Orchard Spreading",
  Org_Size_Facing: "B. 1-3",
  Org_SubCategory: "Contractor - Harvesting and cultivation",
}


const sizeMap = {
  'A. None': '11-30',
  'B. 1-3': '1-3',
  'C. 4-10': '4-10',
  'D. 11 - 30': '11-30',
  'E. 31 - 100': '31-100',
  'F. 100 - 300': '100-300',
  'G. 301 - 1000': '301-1000',
  'H. 1,000+': '1000 +',
  'J. ???': '1-3',
}

for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(companyObj)) {
  if (val in sizeMap) {
    companyObj[key] = sizeMap[val];
    break; // if we dont need to check other properties
  }
}

console.log(companyObj)
```

Note that we are modifying the original object, we could also create a new one if thats a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `for.. in` loop

```js
const companyObj = { 
      Advice_Charge: "B. In service / product cost",
      Org_Advisory: "B. 1-3",
      Org_Developers: "A. None",
      Org_MainCategory: "Business services and sales",
      Org_Name: "A1 Orchard Spreading",
      Org_Size_Facing: "B. 1-3",
      Org_SubCategory: "Contractor - Harvesting and cultivation"
}
const sizeMap = {
       'A. None': '11-30',
       'B. 1-3': '1-3',
       'C. 4-10': '4-10',
       'D. 11 - 30': '11-30',
       'E. 31 - 100': '31-100',
       'F. 100 - 300': '100-300',
       'G. 301 - 1000': '301-1000',
       'H. 1,000+': '1000 +',
       'J. ???': '1-3',
}

for(let key in companyObj) {
   if(companyObj[key] in sizeMap) {
      let val = companyObj[key];
      companyObj[key] = sizeMap[val];
   }
}

console.log(companyObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite your original object you can do this:

```js
if(sizeMap.hasOwnProperty(companyObj.Org_Size_Facing)){
    companyObj.Org_Size_Facing = sizeMap[companyObj.Org_Size_Facing]
}
```

Otherwise you can create a new object:

```js
let newObj = {};

if(sizeMap.hasOwnProperty(companyObj.Org_Size_Facing)){
    newObj.Org_Size_Facing = sizeMap[companyObj.Org_Size_Facing]
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newMap = sizeMap[companyObj.Org_Size_Facing];
if (newMap != undefined)
    companyObj.Org_Size_Facing = newMap;
```